# how to load my directive with data from service

Tags: angularjs

Below is my code and I can't get the data into directive to draw canvas. I want to update the text from textarea on canvas.
html code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="textCtrl">
```

Comment: are you sure your ng-change work fine ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create service and controller, try this code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <textarea ng-model="data">

            </textarea>

        </div>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" txt-img txt-data="data" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #7d0f8b;"></canvas>



    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

directly inject the contenu of your textarea in your directive.

```
app.directive('txtImg', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'AEC',

    scope:{
       data:"=txt-data"
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr){
        var c = el[0];
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(scope.data,20,20);

    }
}
});
```

and in your controller:

```
app.controller('textCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = "";
});
```

Comment: I agree, but perhaps he has the service for other purposes too. It shouldn't be a problem injecting a service into a directive.

Comment: @hubert Thanks for your answer. I am learning angular and I wanted to use service for practicing it and also I would like to use it for other purposes too

Comment: Change your example and use one where the service is neccessary.

Comment: @Thya for example, if you want to save the content of the text-area in external JSon?????? You can't use service to do this.